# Laravel API - Trying to get property of non-object | 500 - But it is an object

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api

Laravel Api.

Endpoint: `Route::get('users/{user}/boards', 'Api\ApiBoardController@index');`

Controller: `return $user;`

Request: `/api/users/5/boards`

Response: `{"id":5,"name":"Patryk Gierda","email":"emailooo@o2.pl","created_at":"2018-03-22 15:34:24","updated_at":"2018-03-22 15:34:24"}`

This is an object. Even tried to check with `return Response::json((string)is_object($user));`

But this `return Response::json($user->boards);` or this `return $user->boards;` result in

`{"message":"Trying to get property of non-object","status_code":500}`

While `$user->boards` normally works and result in collection of models.

Boards method:

```
public function boards()
{
    $participatesIn = Board_User::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
    return Board::whereIn('id', $participatesIn->pluck('board_id'))->get();
}
```

And this works on web endpoint and in views etc...

But somehow API has problem with it.

How `Trying to get property of non-object`? It is an object.

What is the problem here? Trying, thinking, looking on web and can't find the problem, answer and solution.

Edit:

I found out that the problem is with authentication?

First in controller I made `Auth::login($user);` and now it works perfectly...

But how to make this work without it? Remove this need of auth? I don't know how to proceed with this.

I don't need any auth for this endpoint.

Comment: `auth()->user()` is probably null

Comment: Did you debugged it with xdebug?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte But I don't want to have any auth and I don't need it completly

Comment: Ok, which value do you want to use instead?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I don't understand, what value?

Comment: Calling `Auth::login($user)` is not a solution. If you already have `$user` to be able to log them in, why can you not just use `$user->id` instead of `auth()->user()->id`?